# Why is 'subscribe' function not registering? RxJava Android Studio

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm writing code for a splash screen as part of a project but when I am trying to use RxJava all the other functions are working fine until I get to 'subscribe' which isn't registering so I'm wondering am I missing a library I didn't import or something?

The error message I get when trying to run is: 'Cannot resolve method 'subscribe'. I've tried asking the tutorial creator, as well as looking at the top relevant questions about the 'subscribe' function on StackOverflow and even looking at the full list of methods in the Completable library but I can't find a solution so I'm really desperate, *please help*

These are my dependencies:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20'
```

My Code:

```
package codebymech.fyprideshareapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.functions.Action;


public class Activity_SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        delay_Splash();
    }

        private void delay_Splash() {
            Completable.timer(delay: 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() throws Exception {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity_SplashScreen.this, "!! Splash Screen Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Part of tutorial where the code is from:
https://youtu.be/144TuYxEu2M?t=489

Comment: I've tried the subscribeOn and other subscribe methods but those don't flag as methods either so I feel like there's some library or dependency I'm missing or using the wrong version of? Also I used Java 1.8 and the sdk build version is 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `delay:` . This is not possible in Java. If you look at the video, you see a `delay:` in given method, but it is added by the IDE (IntelliJ) in order to give you a hint, which parameter you are currently editing.

Import

```
import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Action;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

Java8

```
   Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            Schedulers.trampoline())
            .subscribe(() -> {
               System.out.println("x");
            });
```

Java7

```
    Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            Schedulers.trampoline())
            .subscribe(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("x");
                }
            });
```

Comment: You're a life saver honestly, I would have never noticed that it'd be something so small. Thanks so much for the help.